# GetListItemChangesSinceToken returns code": "-2130575251" Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office365apis

I'm trying to retrieve the change from my 'Documents' List since last token from my sharepoint Online site.

I'm doing the following:

POST:

```
https://pragmaticcoders.sharepoint.com/raccoon%20site/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/GetListItemChangesSinceToken
```

Request Header:

```
Cookie: odbn=1; FedAuth=...; WSS_FullScreenMode=false; rtFa=...
```

Request Body:

```
{
    'query': {
        '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.ChangeLogItemQuery'
        }, 
    'ChangeToken':'1;3;482e418a-0900-414b-8902-    02248c2e44e8;634955266749500000;5749111'
    }
}
```

This cookie is valid as i can retrieve Lists, Folders contents

```
/_api/Web/Lists
_api/Web/Lists(guid'aUID')/Items
```

But when I made the query for `GetListItemChangesSinceToken`, I got the following result :

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone shed some light on why I got this specific error please?

Comment: if you log in as the user you are authenticating as can you see the audit log in the GUI? Have you worked through the steps here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2009/12/04/content-deployment-the-complete-guide-part-7-change-token-basics/

Comment: Hi ghangas, thanks for taking a look at my issue,  we might not talk about the same things though, what i'm doing is simply query the api of sharepoint online (via office365 developer account) via curl on linux machine, i dont understand what you are referring to by logs and GUI, can you explain me please ?

Comment: Yes. Most code components can be triggered in the GUI. Verifying that your user has permissions to make the query will help you isolate code and perms. The GUI is not your end goal, but by going to the SharePoint online site (not through the api) you can test whether you can view the history of changes (but use the account you run your code with)

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be that context is expired.
You need to update(or set, if not set) **X-RequestDigest** header.
Using method:

> http(s)://***your web***/_api/contextinfo

[More info here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)